# WebApi Client. PostAsJson

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api2

I have some strange problem. I am using `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3` for simple .NET client for API. I want to post some data to API. I am using `PostAsJsonAsync` method for it.

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var adress = new Uri("http://localhost:28906/v1/things?access_token=SOMETOKEN");
            var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(adress, new ThingModel() { Name = "test"});

        }
```

When I am sending request, my uri is transformed from `"http://localhost:28906/v1/things?access_token=SOMETOKEN"` to `"http://localhost:28906/v1/things/?access_token=SOMETOKEN"` ( '/' is inserted before '?'). And request becomes wrong. How can I overcome this? In fact, how can I pass query string and json body?

Comment: Just for testing don't use the `Uri` and try putting the string directly into the `PostAsJsonAsync` method and see if it still includes the trailing slash before the `?`

Comment: It includes. It is very strange

Comment: I created some unit tests for the code you entered and they pass. No trailing slash is added when I inspect the request sent. I am unable to reproduce your particular issue.